# View memory content of non-managed memory in .Net

Tags: .net, memory, memory-leaks, dllimport

I have a third-party C/C++ DLL that I call using `DllImport`:

```
internal static class wrapper {
    [DllImport("vendor.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int execute_action(int a, int b);

    [DllImport("vendor.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int free_memory();
}
```

I have a suspicion that the "free memory" method I call is not actually releasing all the memory it addressed, but maybe it's just the measurement that's wrong, with the memory being made available back to the process but not the OS.

Can I check what the non-managed part of my process has stored in memory? I tried ANTS Memory Profiler, but of course I can only inspect managed memory...

Comment: DLLs don't own memory. Processes do. If you want to test just run an allocate deallocate cycle in a loop and see if it can run forever.

Comment: Of course, sorry for the shortcut... that's an interesting idea but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: No. Because the point is that the question has no answer because DLLs don't own memory.

Comment: There you go...